# Will changed permissions trigger rsync to download again?

Tags: rsync

I'm running a large rsync job which has been running for hours and will run for a couple more.

I need to change permissions on the downloaded files to access them from my web app but I'm worried it will break the copy job?

Do I have to worry or doesn't the permissions have anything to do with the sync itself?

I'm copying with `rsync -rchavzP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends... If changing the permissions result in rsync being unable to read and/or write on your webserver the job should fail.

Normally a change of permissions is handled intelligently and rsync will only change the permissions if the file hasn't changed, without transferring the file itself.  The option `--no-perms` should ensure that a difference in permissions on the target location won't be "corrected".

In earlier versions  of rsync the full file list used to determine what to copy were generated first and IIRC later changes in the local/or remote file lists after initial scan that wouldn't be picked up, allowing you to change permissions and such but

> `-r, --recursive` ... Beginning  with rsync 3.0.0, the recursive algorithm used is now
>   an incremental scan that uses much less memory than  before  and
>   begins the transfer after the scanning of the first few directories have been completed. ...
>  
>    Some  options require rsync to know the full file list, so these options disable the incremental recursion mode.  These  include: `--delete-before, --delete-after, --prune-empty-dirs,` and
>    `--delay-updates`.

So if both local and remote rsync versions are above 3.0.0 you need to know if rsync has already completely finished with a certain directory before applying changed permissions.

Better to completely avoid the problem of course and use rsync to set to correct permisions in the first place with somthing like `rsync --no-p --chmod=ugo=rwX`

> `--chmod`  This  option  tells  rsync  to apply one or more comma-separated  `chmod`
>   The  resulting value is treated as though it was the permissions
>   that the sending side supplied for the file ...

Check the manual for more on that.

For long rsync jobs you may benefit from the delay updates option:

> `--delay-updates`
>   This option puts the temporary file from each updated file  into
>   a holding directory until the end of the transfer, at which time
>   all the files are renamed into place in rapid succession.   This
>   attempts to make the updating of the files a little more atomic.